# How to view a file that's part of an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, pdf, filenotfoundexception, server-error

I have a file, `eulatest.pdf`, that I want to be able to view through my website. At this point I don't really care whether it's at `mywebsite.com/eulatest.pdf` or `mywebsite.com/eula/eulatest.pdf` or any variation; I can't get any of these to work. How can I view this file? I'm not even trying to access it through code; I just can't figure out where it is or how to access it at all.

I keep getting this error:

[image: The resource cannot be found]

And I've tried putting the file in all of these locations:

[image: Solution Explorer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an action in one of your controllers to stream out that file.

```
public class EULAController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return File("eulatest.pdf","application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Assuming the file is in the root folder of your application. For more on File checkout [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

If this is in EULA Controller use:

```
 mywebsite.com/eula/
```

Alternatively you can add that file to ignore lists in your route mapping.